# locally stored package not found

Tags: org-mode, load-path

I am trying to use the setup of `org-cite` and `org-ref-cite` described on jkitchin’s org-ref-cite repository (https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref-cite) but I keep getting the error

> Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, org-cite.

My adjusted setup is:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/XXX/github/org-mode/lisp/")

(use-package org-cite
  :load-path "/Users/XXX/github/org-mode/lisp/"
  :config
 (require 'oc-csl)
  )
```

The folder `org-mode` is the git-repo from https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode

Using Emacs 27.2 and `use-package` is also installed.

I cannot find any difference to the setup of the repo above. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post the same question to emacs.SE and Stack Overflow. Please choose one to keep and delete the other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has also been discussed elsewhere: https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref-cite/issues/20

To make it short:

For `org-cite` the name for the package has been changed to `oc`.

Loading `org-cite` with

```
(use-package oc
  :load-path  "/Users/xxx/github/org-mode/lisp/"
  :config
  (require 'oc-csl))
```

works fine.

**But** if you load `org` before-hand, load it also with this specific path:

```
(use-package org
  :load-path  "/Users/xxx/github/org-mode/lisp/"
  :ensure nil
.
.
.
```